# how can i echo the information processed by an included file

Tags: php

how can i echo the information processed by an included file,: 
please explain

```html
<div class="col-lg-8">
 <a id="toggle" onclick="showorhide('phorder')"  class="btn btn-default" >Show / Hide <? echo $phname; ?> Transactions History</a>
 <br><br>
 <div id="phorder">
  <? include ("phtrx.php"); ?>
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <a id="toggle" onclick="showorhide('ghorder')"  class="btn btn-default" >Show / Hide <? echo $phname; ?> Transactions History</a>
 <br><br>
 <div id="ghorder">
  <? include ("ghtrx.php"); ?>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
 <div class="ui green buttons">
  <a id="toggle" onclick="showorhide('phlist')" class="btn btn-default" >Show / Hide <? echo $skph; ?> Request</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

see the code above, please explain better

Comment: what's in the file? it should use echo\print inside php or if its raw text\html it would automatically appear

Answer (score 0):

**file-to-include.php:**

```
<?php $who="world"; ?>
```

**file1.php:**

```
<?php include 'file-to-include.php' ;?>
Hello <?php echo $who; ?>!
```